# Add Library to Footer

Tags: 7, theming

If I am using the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module to add a javascript library in my module, is it possible to have the library load in the footer instead of the header?

If not is there an alternative method?

Comment: https://groups.drupal.org/node/8399 check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the libraries_load() function:

```
$library = libraries_load('easyzoom');
```

I just used the libraries_get_path() function to get the path and attached to the element and added scope of footer.

```
$easyzoom_library_path = libraries_get_path('easyzoom');

$element['#attached']['js'] = array(
  $easyzoom_library_path . '/dist/easyzoom.js' => array('scope' => 'footer'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope parameter of drupal_add_js to specify the location of your script.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
    array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
  );
```

Follow [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) for more details and examples of drupal_add_js